# How to add custom dimensions to App Insights request telemetry in an ASGI web application?

Tags: python, azure-application-insights, open-telemetry

I have a python web application using Quart. Here is how I add boilerplate App Insights request telemetry to it:

```
...
from opentelemetry.sdk.trace import TracerProvider
from opentelemetry.sdk.trace.export import BatchSpanProcessor
from opentelemetry.instrumentation.asgi import OpenTelemetryMiddleware
from azure.monitor.opentelemetry.exporter import AzureMonitorTraceExporter

bp = Blueprint("routes", __name__, static_folder='static')

def create_app():
    tracer_provider = TracerProvider()
    tracer_provider.add_span_processor(BatchSpanProcessor(AzureMonitorTraceExporter()))

    app = Quart(__name__)
    app.asgi_app = OpenTelemetryMiddleware(app.asgi_app, tracer_provider = tracer_provider)
    app.register_blueprint(bp)
    return app
...
```

I also set the `APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING` environment variable to the App Insights connection string.

And it works - I get boilerplate request telemetry in the App Insights.

Now I want to enrich the request telemetry with custom dimensions. I know the theory of it:

1. Have request scoped singleton exposing a dictionary.
2. At any point in code we can add entries to that dictionary
3. Just before the request is over there is code to send App Insights telemetry. There should be a way to customize this code in one way or another to add the dictionary to the request telemetry as `customDimensions`.

We have implemented it in our Asp.Net application. But I have no idea how to translate this into python web app using Quart.

**EDIT 1**

For Asp.Net Core the logic implementation is trivial:

1. Configure the connection string to the App Insights. Could be done through the environment similarly to python, only the environment variable is different (`ApplicationInsights__ConnectionString`)
2. Add `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore` nuget package.
3. Add `services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(opt => opt.EnableActiveTelemetryConfigurationSetup = true);` to `Startup.ConfigureServices`

This gives us boilerplate request telemetry. And I have it in python too. To enrich it with custom telemetry in Asp.Net Core we do not even need to hook into the code that sends the telemetry. We just need to execute the following code:

```
var telem = context.Features.Get<RequestTelemetry>();
telem.Properties[Key] = Value;
```

This adds the Key-Value pair to the list of the custom dimensions of the current request.

E.g. https://www.aspnetmonsters.com/2020/03/2020-03-07-enhancing-application-insights-request-telemetry/

In our C# code, we register the following singleton:

```
public class EnrichRequest : IEnrichRequest
{
    public void EnrichHttpRequest(HttpContext context, Dictionary<string, string> properties)
    {
        var telem = context.Features.Get<RequestTelemetry>();
        foreach (var prop in properties)
        {
            telem.Properties.Add(prop.Key, prop.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

So the singleton is global (not even scoped to a request), but the passed `context` parameter represents the current request, which the caller can get from any point through the DI friendly [IHttpContextAccessor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.ihttpcontextaccessor?view=aspnetcore-8.0) interface, which provides the context of the current request.

As you can see, enrich request telemetry in Asp.Net Core is very simple. The question now - how can we do it in python Quart application?

Comment: I recommend to add an existing code snippet of .NET code and ask how to accomplish this in Python.

Comment: It will take some time, since the code is a framework code developed by another team, but let me try to do that.

Comment: Thanks, this has improved the question. I do not have a quick answer yet, but hopefully others might help.

Answer (score 0):

How about exploring the [guidance for modifying OpenTelemetry (Application Insights)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/opentelemetry-add-modify?tabs=aspnetcore%2Caspnetcore-1%2Caspnetcore-2%2Caspnetcore-3%2Caspnetcore-4%2Caspnetcore-5%2Caspnetcore-6%2Caspnetcore-8%2Caspnetcore-9%2Caspnetcore-10%2Caspnetcore-11%2Caspnetcore-12%2Caspnetcore-13%2Caspnetcore-14%2Caspnetcore-15#modify-telemetry) and [examples provided by the library `azure-monitor-opentelemetry`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/main/sdk/monitor/azure-monitor-opentelemetry#examples)?

The guidance about [currently supported custom telemetry types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/opentelemetry-add-modify?tabs=aspnetcore%2Cpython-1%2Cpython-2%2Cpython-3%2Caspnetcore-4%2Caspnetcore-5%2Cpython-6%2Cpython-8%2Cpython-9%2Cpython-10%2Cpython-11%2Cpython-12%2Cpython-13%2Caspnetcore-14%2Cpython-15#collect-custom-telemetry) states that custom request telemetry is supported for Python using OpenTelemetry API.

Use Cases

- [Add a custom property to a Span](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/opentelemetry-add-modify?tabs=aspnetcore%2Caspnetcore-1%2Caspnetcore-2%2Caspnetcore-3%2Caspnetcore-4%2Caspnetcore-5%2Caspnetcore-6%2Caspnetcore-8%2Cpython-9%2Caspnetcore-10%2Caspnetcore-11%2Caspnetcore-12%2Caspnetcore-13%2Caspnetcore-14%2Caspnetcore-15#add-a-custom-property-to-a-span)

  - Any attributes you add to spans are exported as custom properties. They populate the *customDimensions* field in the requests, dependencies, traces, or exceptions table.
- [Add custom span](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/opentelemetry-add-modify?tabs=aspnetcore%2Caspnetcore-1%2Caspnetcore-2%2Caspnetcore-3%2Caspnetcore-4%2Caspnetcore-5%2Cpython-6%2Cpython-8%2Cpython-9%2Caspnetcore-10%2Caspnetcore-11%2Caspnetcore-12%2Caspnetcore-13%2Caspnetcore-14%2Caspnetcore-15#add-custom-spans)

Since you want to enrich request telemetry with arbitrary custom properties you might have a different use case not supported yet. But give those samples a try and may be you find out how to get the span for the current request and add custom properties.

Comment: I have not noticed any relevant example. To create a custom dimension is probably not a problem. The issue is pluging into the code that sends the telemetry and having a scoped singleton to expose the dictionary to any point in the code. I have not seen any examples for that.

Comment: With regard to auto-instrumentation of python web frameworks I found that blog post helpful: https://bargsten.org/wissen/python-logging-azure-custom-dimensions/